# How to use default font for English with Babel?

Tags: fonts, luatex, babel, hebrew

I use `babel` to do my homework in Hebrew, but I often need to use English. I am using a custom font for Hebrew ([Assistant](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Assistant)), but I want to keep using the default font for English (at least until I decide I want something else). Right now, it seems to use the custom font for both Hebrew and English despite the fact I configured it as a Hebrew font.

Here's a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[ItalicFont=*-Regular, ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3}]{Assistant}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}[ItalicFont=*-Regular, ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3}]{Assistant}

\begin{document}
שלום לכולם.

\foreignlanguage{english}{Hello there}
\end{document}
```

I thought that using `babelfont[hebrew]` tells it to use this font only for Hebrew, but I guess I was wrong. How can I tell it to keep using the default font for English?

Comment: The Assistant font would appear to be a sans-serif font. Why do you assign it to the roman font family as well (via `\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[...]{Assistant}`?

Comment: I do get the default Latin Modern font from your example (compiling with LuaLaTeX but using a different Hebrew font). @Mico I don't think there's much of a tradition of serif/non-serif fonts in Hebrew.

Comment: I do get Latin Modern, too. I’m not sure it helps, buy try making them slightly different (for example, add `Scale=1.0001` to the `sf` font).

Comment: @JavierBezos when I add the line `\foreignlanguage{english}{\expandafter\meaning\the\font}` to his settings I don't get that this is Latin Modern. Also, if I add color to his font deceleration it affects the english text as well.

Comment: @UdiFogiel Adding `Color` or `Scale` parameters to the Hebrew font only affects that font for me.

Comment: @AlanMunn after updating it seems to affect the hebrew font only.

Comment: @Mico The person commenting about updating is not the OP. We have no comments from the OP about whether their problem is solved.

Comment: @AlanMunn - Thanks for bringing this issue to my attention. I had definitely misinterpreted the situation. I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: I just updated my packages as @UdiFogiel suggested, and it indeed solve my issue. Quite weird I must admit.

Comment: @ShaiAvr Thanks for letting us know. We'll close the question then.